# How to find objects when you only enter a part of phone number or enter name that this name (may be uppercase ,lowercase) => still produce the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-frontend

```
 let obj = [
    {
        name: 'jame',
        phone: 123456
    },
    {
        name: 'alex',
        phone: 456789
    }
]
```

> i'm creating app manager contact include functions .
>
> 1. Input contact
> 2. Delete contact
> 3. Change contact
> 4. Find contact
> 5. Save and Exit  
>      help me part 4

Comment: Do you want to find the `name` from the value entered in an `input` element?

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate the Array (or use `find` or `findIndex`) and check phone key.

Search with [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

You need to convert the search string and key value to lower/upper case to make it case insensitive search.

A sample code would look like this. (Please note that this returns the first match, if you need full list use filter, see other answers.)

```js
let obj = [{
    name: 'jame',
    phone: 123456
  },
  {
    name: 'alex',
    phone: 456789
  }
];

function Search(arr, searchString, searchKey) {

  return arr.find((item) => String(item[searchKey]).toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()));

}

console.log(Search(obj, 'Lex', 'name'));

console.log(Search(obj, 'me', 'name'));

console.log(Search(obj, '89', 'phone'));
```

Comment: @KhoaVõĐức My solution returns the first match, to get all matches use `filter`. I am not adding filter in my solution as there are other solutions which uses `filter`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `filter` method of array with String method `includes`.

```js
let obj = [
    {
        name: 'jame',
        phone: 123456
    },
    {
        name: 'alex',
        phone: 456789
    }
]
function searchcontact(obj, query) {
    let searchTerm = String(query).toLocaleLowerCase();
    let result = obj.filter( item =>{
        if(item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) || item.phone.toString().includes(searchTerm)) {
            return  item;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
console.log(searchcontact(obj, "jame"));
console.log(searchcontact(obj, "456"));
console.log(searchcontact(obj, "alex"));
```

Comment: i'm sorry my english not well, but thank your so much helped me

Comment: @Sohail looks like someone down voted all solutions in the page :(

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong you may want to search data from phone or email within an object in upper or lower case.

If that so then try below code call function on keypress or whatever event you like:

```
obj = [
{
  name : 'jame',
  phone : 123456
},
{
name : 'alex',
phone : 456789
}
]


var updateSearch = search => {

var  newObj = obj.filter(function (item) {
  let itemData = item.name ? item.name.toLowerCase() : ''.toLowerCase();
  let textData = search.toLowerCase();
  return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;

});


console.log(newObj);

};
```